# Hostgator web server corrupts png, jpg, gif, doc, docx, odt, pdf file types when uploaded; it doesn't corrupt bmp, svg and rtf file types though

Tags: image, webserver, document, web-hosting, corrupt

I have got a website which is hosted by Hostgator. The problem is that when I try to upload new png, jpg, gif, doc, docx, pdf or odt documents/images, the server automatically corrupts them. This means that these file types aren't displayed/downloaded on the website at all.

When I upload new bmp, svg and rtf images/documents, the server doesn't automatically corrupt them and these file types are displayed/downloaded on the website perfectly fine.

All images/documents, including png,jpg, gif, doc, docx, odt etc, display/download perfectly if they are already on the server. This problem is just for new uploads. Also if you overwrite an image/document with a new upload, it automatically corrupts it.

I have rang Hostgator who can't help me because it's outside their scope.

Just one last thing, I will provide a link with a broken image:
http://www.clmedaid.co.uk/images/img/ICO.png

I am Baffled; if anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .htaccess command to change the display allowances for the server? This can be a huge help in some cases. After looking at your site the 404 page doesn't have any images displaying either, when compared to a normal hostgator 404 page it is apparent that the server configuration is incorrect. I'd recommend contacting the server admin or the company again and seeing what they say when you explain you've tried modifying the .htacess and had no luck.